# picocom out put in raspberry pi terminal

Tags: raspbian, serial

I have run this in terminal,

```
sudo picocom /dev/ttyAMAO
```

and output gives,

```
picocom v1.7

port is        : /dev/ttyAMAO
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 9600
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv
imap is        :
omap is        :
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,

Termial Ready
```

and serial out put prints from my sensor.

simply I want to remove all details and change `Teminal ready`
to `Sensor is ready`

can any one help me on this?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy because that is one of the biggest advantages of open source software

While the answer to question has very little to do with specifically to raspbian or serial communications on the PI, I will still answer it.

Steps

- Download or `git clone` the picocom source code from [here](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom)
- Edit source file [picocom.c](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom/blob/18ae4385a76e03d06b2e1d1e26ffb87ae8d37200/picocom.c) and change the text on line 1577
- Build and run.

`make`

`make install` # if you want to overwrite the system package's version (probably not required)

- you can/will need to install the `build-essentials` package to get the complete compiler suite

`apt-get install build-essentials`